# Specific behaviour of {if else} in C

Tags: c, performance, if-statement, big-o

I have a functioning binary array search algorithm, here it is:

```
int binarySearch(int array[],int n,int elem){

    int high =n-1;  
    int low = 0;
    int mid;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(elem>array[mid]){
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else if(elem<array[mid]){
            high=mid-1; 
        }
        else return mid;
    }   
    return -1;
}
```

but now I want to know the amount of comparisons made between elements of the array, I know how to do that, but my questions are:

When the compiler finds one of the clauses to be true, does it still go into the other clauses?
example: when `elem>array[mid]` it makes one comparison, so now he should know that the following `else if` is `false`, but does it still make the comparison?

And what about the `else`? when he found the `if` and `else if` to be `false`, does he secretly make a comparison `(elem==array[mid])`?

Comment: @Adrianio use mid = low + (high -low)/2 . Joe bentley says writing bug fre binary search is tricky .

Comment: @Novak007 Eh? You either move low/high or you move and retain the mid. This algorithm moves low/high. The latter is more common as far as I know. There's no bug here, but there will certainly be one if the OP changes the code like you suggest.

Comment: @Lundin What if low + high exceeds the integer limit ? In that case the other approach won't usually overflow.  And there will be no bug when that is done.

Comment: @Novak007 In that case the bug is "programmer picked the wrong data type" and nothing else. In which case you shouldn't run off and do "clever fixes because I picked the wrong data type", but instead actually pick the correct data type. `size_t` makes more sense than `int` in this case (`int` is almost never the correct data type), but if you are truly concerned about integer overflow you should declare all integers as `uint32_t` and then write `mid = (uint32_t) ( (uint64_t)low + (uint64_t)high ) / 2;`. Also some sanity-check of the caller is needed anyhow. What if `n` is zero?

Comment: @Lundin yes got your point but its recommended, i found somewhere. And I didn't get why there will be a bug introduced when I  do that ?

Comment: @Novak007 I misunderstood your comment at first, I thought you were suggesting an algorithm change and not a protection against integer overflow. Anyway, be wary of random generic recommendations and "clever" tricks, but instead always consider the true source of the bug. Why would we get an integer overflow here? Must be because source code documentation didn't specify an upper limit of `n` (needs to be fixed). In which case the programmer didn't even consider such a limit. In which case the whole function needs to be rewritten to handle the maximum value that `n` is allowed to have.

Answer (score 3):

> when elem>array[mid] it makes one comparison, so now he should know
>   that the following "else if" is false, but does it still make the
>   comparison?

No. If the first `if` statement is true, then the following `if else` and `else` clauses won't be executed.

> And what about the "else"? when he found the "if" and "else if" to be
>   false, does he secretly make a comparison (elem==array[mid])?

No. The final `else` will be executed unconditionally in this case. No secret comparsion will be made.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess, if I want to know the exact number of comparisons, this would do?
`if(elem>array[mid]){
   low=mid+1;
   CCount++;
  }
  else if(elem<array[mid]){
   high=mid-1;
   CCount+=2; 
  }
  else{
   CCount+=2;
   return mid;
  }`

@Gopi @Sourav Kanta

Comment: No. The first comparison will *always* be done. So the `CCount++` needs to be outside the if` statement. You can use: ``CCount++`; if(elem>array[mid]){ low=mid+1;} else if(elem<array[mid]){ high=mid-1; CCount++; } else{ CCount++; return mid; }` to get the exact no of comparisons made. But I don't see what you want to achieve with this though.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I know the first comparison has to always be made, that's why I put CCount +=2 in the 'else if' and 'else', both solutions are right, according to the number of coparisons I got, but I guess yours is cleaner :)
And I'm just studying the efficiency of some algorithms.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler keeps on checking from the start of a if - else if clause.If any one condition is true it skips all the other else ifs and else comparisons.However when you work with if-if clause it checks all possible conditions and excecutes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cond) ..
else if (condn)..
else ...
```

So just to put it simply when `if` condition passes `else if` and `else` conditions are ignored only when `if` is false `elseif` is checked and when `if` and `elseif` both are false `else` will be executed without considering conditions internally.

Answer (score 0):

**if-else** structures can sometimes be hard to follow.  When you see something like:

```
if(elem>array[mid]){
        low=mid+1;
    }
    else if(elem<array[mid]){
        high=mid-1; 
    }
    else return mid;
```

it may help to notice that the if-else pairs are nested. It's easier to see with some parentheses. Take for example one if-else statement pair:

```
if(condition)
    { something;
    }
else(condition)
    { something;
    }
```

If the `if` condition is satisfied, the `else` portion will not be executed.

**Applying this principle:**
This can be extended to your code.  It could functionally be rewritten as:

```
if(elem>array[mid])
     {
        low=mid+1;
     }
else {
       if(elem<array[mid])
      {
       high=mid-1; 
      }
       else
          return mid;
    }
```

As you can see, the second if-else pair is nested within the first `else` statement. This way, if the first `if` condition is true, nothing else will be executed.

I hope this helps.